# Issue with SQL join and group

Tags: sql, join, group-by

I have 4 tables I am trying to join and then group data. The data consists of jobs, invoices and accounts. I want to generate a total of each account in each job.

I have the following tables:

**Jobs**

```
| ID | JobNumber |
|----|-----------|
|  1 | J200      |
|  2 | J201      |
```

**Job_Invoices**

```
| ID | InvoiceNumber | JobID |
|----|---------------|-------|
| 10 |     I300      |   1   |
| 11 |     I301      |   2   |
```

**Invoice_Accounts**

```
| ID | InvoiceId | AccountID | Amount |
|----|-----------|-----------|--------|
| 23 |   10      |     40    |  200   |
| 24 |   10      |     40    |  300   |
| 25 |   10      |     41    |  100   |
| 26 |   11      |     40    |  100   |
```

**Accounts**

```
| ID | Name |
|----|------|
| 40 | Sales|      
| 41 | EXP  |
```

I am trying the following:

```
SELECT  
    J.JobNumber,
    A.Name AS "Account",
    SUM(JA.Amount) AS 'Total'
FROM 
    Job J
LEFT JOIN 
    Job_Invoices JI ON JI.JobID = J.JobID
INNER JOIN 
    Invoice_Accounts JA ON JA.InvoiceId = JI.ID
INNER JOIN 
    Accounts A ON A.ID = JA.AccountID
GROUP BY 
    J.JobNumber, A.Name, JA.Amount
ORDER BY 
    J.JobNumber
```

What I expect:

```
| JobNumber | Account   | Total |
|-----------|-----------|-------|
| J200      |   EXP     |  100  |
| J200      |   Sales   |  500  |
| J201      |   Sales   |  100  |
```

What I get:

```
| JobNumber | Account   | Total |
|-----------|-----------|-------|
| J200      |   EXP     |  100  |
| J200      |   Sales   |  200  |
| J200      |   Sales   |  300  |
| J201      |   Sales   |  100  |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `Job` table in the query.  The `INNER JOIN`s are to the `Job_Invoices` table, so the outer join is turned into an inner join anyway.

So, you can simplify this to:

```
SELECT JI.JobNumber, A.Name AS Account, SUM(JA.Amount) AS Total
FROM Job_Invoices JI JOIN
     Invoice_Accounts JA
     ON JA.InvoiceId = JI.ID JOIN
     Accounts A
     ON A.ID = JA.AccountID
GROUP BY JI.JobNumber, A.Name
ORDER BY JI.JobNumber;
```

Also note that you don't need to escape the column aliases.  The just makes the query harder to type.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you have the `JA.Amount` in your `GROUP BY` clause. Try taking it out:

```sql
    SELECT J.JobNumber, A.Name AS "Account", SUM(JA.Amount) AS 'Total'
    FROM Job J
    LEFT JOIN Job_Invoices JI ON JI.JobID = J.JobID
    INNER JOIN Invoice_Accounts JA ON JA.InvoiceId = JI.ID
    INNER JOIN Accounts A ON A.ID = JA.AccountID 
    GROUP BY J.JobNumber, A.Name
    ORDER BY J.JobNumber
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a query as:

```
select sum (IA.Amount) as Amount, J.JobNumber,A.Name
from @Invoice_Accounts IA --as it holds the base data
join @Job_Invoices JI on IA.InvoiceId = JI.ID
join @Jobs J on J.id = JI.JobID
join @Accounts A on A.ID = IA.AccountID
group by J.JobNumber,A.Name
```

Included the `Jobs` table as it has the `JobNumber` column. [Sample code here..](https://rextester.com/JGCUG52472)